Deeplinking scroll Issue with Swagger UI React application
I have some OpenAPI 3.0.1 files and I am using the swagger-ui-react npm package. I have 2 files from which 1 file contains servers like this:
servers:
  - url: https://{Environment}api.abc.com/test
    variables:
      Environment:
        default: dev
        enum:
          - dev
          - staging

and the second file contains servers like this:
servers:
  - url: https://api.def.com/Prod

I also have enabled deeplinking in the application through the following code:
<div className='ml-[15rem] min-w-[100rem] mt0'>
    <SwaggerUIReact spec={openApiData} deepLinking={true} docExpansion="list" supportedSubmitMethods={['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']} />
</div>

My problem arises when I select an API it generates its URL and when I hit that URL the scrolling works perfect for the second API (without environment variables). In the first API, the scrolling goes to a little above from where it should supposed to go. I have attached the screenshot.

I think it is the environment issue because when I add environment variables, it is allocating some space for it here,

which can cause the issue of scrolling. But I do not want to remove these servers.
What should I do or is there any Swagger UI configuration I can add for it to fix it?
